# How can I select the value from dropdown list where I need to choose value from drop-down list only?

Tags: java, selenium

In my case I am bound to select the value from drop down list only.
send key as "Goibibo" is different from what I choose from drop down.
So can you please help me to select the value?

[image]

```
<input id="companyQuery" class="shadow-in tooltips fileSimilar" type="text" value="" onkeypress="javascript:populateCompanies();" data-name="company name" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Company Name (Complaint Against)') {this.value = '';}" name="complaintUserDTO.companyName" data-placement="right" rel="popover" placeholder="Company name" autocomplete="off" style="border-color: rgb(204, 204, 204); border-width: 1px; border-style: solid;">

GeneralMethods.driver.findElement(By.id("companyQuery")).sendKeys("Goibibo");  
            Select dropdown = new Select (GeneralMethods.driver.findElement(By.id("companyQuery")));
            dropdown.selectByValue("Goibibo");
```

I tried to select the element by using Select class but no luck

Comment: What you have tried and please share html code part of that dropdown.

Comment: @HelpingHands I have Edited my question, have shared html code.

Comment: is that dropdown in javascript popup?

Comment: Please copy the html code of the dropdown menu. I think the JS adds it to the DOM only after you typed something.

Answer (score 0):

your selecting drop down option using selectByValue(), but the value is empty in html code. so do use selectByVisibleText()  instead SelectByValue().

use below lines of code:

```
 WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("companyQuery"));
 Select selectOption= new Select(element);
 selectOption.selectByVisibleText("Goibibo");
```